# nHibernate Formula Containing A Join

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

When I specify the following formula:

```
Map(x => x.PendingInviteCount)
    .Access
    .ReadOnly()
    .Formula("(SELECT COUNT(ui.UserInviteId) 
               FROM [UserInvite] ui JOIN [UserInviteOrganisation] uio 
               ON ui.UserInviteId = uio.UserInviteId 
               WHERE uio.OrganisationId = organisationId)");
```

the sql that is generated looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(ui.UserInviteId) 
FROM [UserInvite] ui 
JOIN [UserInviteOrganisation] organisati0_.uio on ui.UserInviteId = uio.UserInviteId 
WHERE uio.OrganisationId = organisati0_.organisationId
```

which fails due to uio being prefixed with organisatio0_.

Is it possible to create a formula that contains a JOIN?

Comment: Have you tried using the as key word for the alias?

Comment: Oh wow, that works :) Post this as an answer so I can accept it and give you the points.

Comment: All set, put the answer in :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the AS keyword for setting the alias of the table. I don't think that NHibernate picks up on it the way it is currently written.